# Bad request on digest authentication (User: false)

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to implement digest authentication in my app using Passport but I've run into the following problem and can't figure out how to solve it.

When I curl my "protected url" as follows, I get a 400 - Bad request response:

```
    $curl --user test:123456 --digest http://localhost:3000/users
```

You can find the complete curl request/response at the end.

I've tried to use a custom callback for `passport.authenticate` in order to see what is it getting:

```
users.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('digest', {session: false}, function(err, user, info) {
  console.log('Err: %s', err);
  console.log('User: %s', user);
  console.log('Info: %s', info);
})(req, res, next);
}, otherMiddleware);
```

And the result was:

```
Err: null
User: false
Info: Digest realm="Users", nonce="YTFqg2z17mYU039DvuLzONN48F0q1Xmk", qop="auth"
```

So I think that the user is not being sended correctly, but can't figure out why.

I've configured passport to use digest authentication as follows:

- I've tried to left everything setted to default options, so the nonce and realm parameters are setted by passport
- The samples outpout have been taken on different times, that's why the nonce value is not the same.
- If I change the strategy to 'basic' it just works.

index.js:

```
// ...
var passport = require('passport);
var usersRoute = require('./routes/users');

// ...

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use('/users', usersRoute);
```

users.js

```
var passport = require('passport'),
  DigestStrategy = require('passport-http').DigestStrategy,
  User = require('../../models/users');


passport.use(new DigestStrategy({qop: 'auth'},function(username, done) {
  User.findOne({username: username}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {return done(err);}
    if (!user) {return done(null, false);}
    return done(null, user, user.password);
  });
}));

users.get('/', passport.authenticate('digest', {session: false}), function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hi!');
});
```

Then, when I try:

```
$curl --user test:123456 --digest http://localhost:3000/users
```

I get a "400 - Bad request" response.

I left a complete output of the curl command with -v option on it.

```
    Eileen :: ~ » curl -v --user test:123456 --digest http://localhost:3000/users
    * Adding handle: conn: 0x7f858b803a00
    * Adding handle: send: 0
    * Adding handle: recv: 0
    * Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
    * - Conn 0 (0x7f858b803a00) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
    * About to connect() to localhost port 3000 (#0)
    *   Trying ::1...
    *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
    * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
    * Server auth using Digest with user 'test'
    > GET /users HTTP/1.1
    > User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
    > Host: localhost:3000
    > Accept: */*
    >
    < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
    < X-Powered-By: Express
    < WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="Users", nonce="Ah0vZigHMrDx6SMcA3cMeaFm46RtYmv9", qop="auth"
    < Date: Wed, 18 Jun 2014 11:13:58 GMT
    < Connection: keep-alive
    < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    <
    * Ignoring the response-body
    * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
    * Issue another request to this URL: 'http://localhost:3000/users'
    * Found bundle for host localhost: 0x7f858b4151c0
    * Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host localhost
    * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
    * Adding handle: conn: 0x7f858b803a00
    * Adding handle: send: 0
    * Adding handle: recv: 0
    * Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
    * - Conn 0 (0x7f858b803a00) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
    * Server auth using Digest with user 'test'
    > GET /users HTTP/1.1
    > Authorization: Digest username="test", realm="Users", nonce="Ah0vZigHMrDx6SMcA3cMeaFm46RtYmv9", uri="/users", cnonce="ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDE0MDMyNjc5MTY=", nc=00000001, qop=auth, response="7c7d3c5bb1b8882915d3ffe1a2b0231c"
    > User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
    > Host: localhost:3000
    > Accept: */*
    >
    < HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
    < X-Powered-By: Express
    < Date: Wed, 18 Jun 2014 11:13:58 GMT
    < Connection: keep-alive
    < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    <
    * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
    Bad Request%
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue and believe, in both of our cases, the problem is that passport-http does not work with mounted apps.

There is an open pull-request, https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http/pull/16, that may fix the bug if it can be made to pass the CI build.

A workaround is to just remove the Express router instances and pass the app instance around to mount all the endpoints directly on the app object.

Comment: I just ran into this very issue. If you need to fix manually, in your node_modules folder for passport-http. Change line 115 of digest.js from `if (req.url !== creds.uri) {` to `var url = req.originalUrl || req.url;
  if (url !== creds.uri) {`